# vkCmdUpdateBuffer before render pass synchronization?

Tags: vulkan

Does the following:

```
vkCmdUpdateBuffer(c, uniform_buffer, ...);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(c, ...);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(c, ..., uniform_buffer_descriptor, ...);
vkCmdDraw(c, ...);
```

(ie the vkCmdDraw will use the VkBuffer that was just updated by vkCmdUpdateBuffer.)

...require synchronization by a barrier or other means?  Or will the buffer update complete before the draw command executes?  How did you figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a barrier both to make sure the draw doesn't start before the buffer update completes, and to ensure coherence. Commands are *started* in the order they're added to the command buffer, but can operate concurrently and complete out of order. With very few exceptions, any time you have a *data dependency* (aka *hazard*) of the form read-after-write, write-after-write, or write-after-read between two commands, then you need to explicitly enforce ordering and coherence between those commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are about only two expeptions in Vulkan that have implicit synchronization. Everything else must be synchronized by the user.

Le specification:

> This command [`vkCmdUpdateBuffer`] is treated as “transfer” operation, for the purposes of synchronization barriers.